# Azure Pipelines yml - Variable doesn't get substituted in overrideParameters part of AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Dynamically created variable is not interpolated for `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` as part of
`overrideParameters`.

Sample template:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  resourceGroupName: '...'
  storageAccountName: 'actualAccountName'
  subscriptionId: '...'
  location: '...'

steps:      
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Set AzurePipeline var 'sasToken' to 1234"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |            
      $token = 1234;
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sasToken;]$token"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Testing that sasToken is set"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |            
      Write-Host "Token is: $(sasToken)"
      
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'AzureRMServiceConnection'
    subscriptionId: '$(subscriptionId)'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupname)'
    location: $(location)
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'azuretemplates/azuredeploy.json'
    overrideParameters: >-
      -appServiceTemplateUri https://$(storageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/templates/linked-appservice-template.json?$(sasToken)
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

As you can see there is an `override parameters` section where I attempt to append the `$sasToken` using various ways.

So far I have tried:

- $(sasToken)
- ${{ variables.sasToken }}
- $[ variables.sasToken ]

None of these work, and `sasToken` is always empty.

The output url looks like this:

`https://actualAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/templates/linked-appservice-template.json?$(sasToken)`

Note: `$(storageAccountName`) got replaced whereas `$(sasToken)` didn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does you define `sasToken` as a secret?

Comment: Yes its a bearer token with a 10min expiration

Comment: Just for the test, can you make it as `non-secret`? I'm asking for this because this syntax `$(sasToken)` should work but secrets are secured to avoid being disclosed.

Comment: Hi Cristian,
I have tested the code you shared, and I can get the value.
Maybe you can define the sasToken in the variable, and add power shell script to update the value, then use sasToken in overrideParameters.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT I have found a solution after all, sorry for confusion, the sample was oversimplifed. I've added a resonse below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do apologise, my example was oversimplified than the actual yml which used jobs and tasks.

#### Solution:

Variables created using:

`"##vso[task.setvariable variable=sasToken]$token"`

are scoped by default to the `job`

In order to share variables between jobs there are a couple of steps to undertake:

```
      - job: buildJob               #1. name your source job
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: obtainSasTokenTask  #2  name your source task
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'    #4  add isOutput=true;
            script: '##vso[task.setvariable variable=sasToken;isOutput=true]$token'
      - job: build                  #5  name your target job
        dependsOn: ['buildJob']     #6  create a dependency on prev job
        variables:                  #7  create scoped variables an reference your sasToken
            sasToken: $[dependencies.buildJob.outputs['obtainSasTokenTask.sasToken'] ]
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |               #8  use your local $(sasToken)
              Write-Host "Token is: $(sasToken)"
```

Its a terrible multistep process but I haven't found syntax which would be cleaner and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark it as an answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution.